# ngGrid injection into ng-app failed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngGrid due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngGrid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Above is the error message I received. 
I have loaded the ng-grid script AFTER angularjs, jquery.
I injected it into app like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngRoute', 'ngResource','ngGrid'])
.controller('myAppCtrl', myAppCtrl);
```

I wonder where did I do wrong?

**===UPDATE**

Here is my header

```
<!-- Angular Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Third-party Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angular-ui/bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angular-ui/ng-grid3/2.0.7/ng-grid.js"></script>
```

They are all found. No error of 404 return in Chrome Inspector

Comment: Check if ng-grid.js is loaded at all. The cdn is very often down.

Comment: @mainguy I downloaded its lib from the website. Its hosted locally. There is no error returning if the file is not found.

Comment: Could you please share the "head" of your HTML file? Or if you don't have the script declaration there, just share the part where you have the script declaration.

Comment: You can check if ng-grid.js was found by looking at the network tab of firebug. The console does not show any error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USE **ui.grid** not ngGrid

yea. as stupid as it is. Confused by its official GetStarted lol

Comment: ui.grid has replaced ngGrid, and ngGrid has been deprecated. Your answer DID help me figure out my problem though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an error with ui-grid, I used the following ng-grid to solve.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.min.js"></script>
```