# AngularJS ngGrid module declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I've been messing around with Angular and have a simple test project with working however when adding in the module for ngGrid, everything just stops functioning.

A snippet of working HTML is:

```
   <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">{{hdr.title}}</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-click="hdr.setIndex(0)" ng-class="(index==0) ? 'active' : ''">
                    <!--<a href="#">Contributions</a>-->
                    <!--STATE directive-->
                    <a ui-sref="{{hdr.menu[0].state}}">{{hdr.menu[0].name}}</a>
                    <!--<a ui-sref="collections">{{hdr.menu[0].name}}</a>-->
                </li>
                <li ng-click="hdr.setIndex(1)" ng-class="(index==1) ? 'active' : ''">
                    <a ui-sref="{{hdr.menu[1].state}}">{{hdr.menu[1].name}}</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-click="hdr.setIndex(2)" ng-class="(index==2) ? 'active' : ''">
                    <a ui-sref="{{hdr.menu[2].state}}">{{hdr.menu[2].name}}</a>
                </li>


                <!--<li><a href="#"> {{hdr.title}}</a></li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The script contains:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
```

The display fails when the script is updated to either of the following:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngGgrid'])
angular.module('app', ['ngGgrid'])
```

Now instead of the page displaying properly, all that displays is:

```
{{hdr.title}} {{hdr.menu[0].name}} {{hdr.menu[1].name}} {{hdr.menu[2].name}}
```

The script file is being loaded with:

```
    <script src="Scripts/ng-grid.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: You will find an error message in the browser's console.  It could be that it has been loaded before the angular library so check that the order of your script tags is correct, and that the path to ng-grid is correct also

Comment: Thanks.  That led me to the developer tools and based on the message of failing to instantiate the module, another search resulted in the following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746276/nggrid-injection-into-ng-app-failed)

Comment: Good to know for me also. It is best to add the solution as your answer to your question and mark it as accepted

Comment: Will do.  The system has forced me to wait until tomorrow to be able to mark my post as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another keyword search based on the response from [K Scandrettt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544886/k-scandrett) enabled me to locate [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746276/nggrid-injection-into-ng-app-failed) that contained a resolution to my question.